# Can't alt-tab, can't click on programs in the taskbar when I preview them

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, alt-tab

I am having this problem with alt-tabbing where if I alt-tab the program switcher shows up, but it flashes so fast that you can't read it and it also does not actually alt-tab, it stays on the same program.

Another thing that is going wrong is if I hover over opened programs in the taskbar the preview is displayed, but it flashes, and if I try to click on it I can't. If I click on the program in the taskbar it will open, but only if there are not multiples of that program running like two notepads, in which case I can't open either of them.

I have looked in many places to find solutions and couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an issue with your computer having a bad time with Aero so you could try disabling it.

Right Click desktop >> Personalise >> Select 'Windows 7 Basic'.

Does that help?

Comment: My computer is currently running windows 7 basic